# How can I use tomcat jdbc pool with slick?

Tags: scala, tomcat, slick

I want to make my application framework independant, so for starters I want to use:

```
spring mvc
slick
```

So for my data layer I want to use slick, and along with that I want to use tomcat jdbc pool to manage connection pooling as I have read it is one of the best performance wise etc.

How can I setup slick to use this pool?

Are there any example data layers written in slick that aren't really tied down to the play framework?

Comment: So you're looking for a framework that lets you divorce yourself from other frameworks?

Comment: Have you seen this http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/connection.html#using-a-datasource ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "org.apache.tomcat" % "tomcat-jdbc" % "8.0.3" to build.sbt.
2. Follow the next link: http://boldradius.com/blog-post/UwZtbQEAAD0WKXuj/database-connection-issue-with-bonecp-in-play-2 - it is fairly straight forward and allows you to change the default data source.
3. Assuming you have JDBCWrapper in place, next create your db with:

   import scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend._

   ...

   val mydb = Database.forDataSource(JDBCWrapper.datasource)
4. (Optional). I would also suggest to remove the dependency 'jdbc' from your build.sbt, this way you ensure you surely use tomcat pool rather than default one (BoneCP).